# How to register an app in Microsoft's registration portal for debug?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office-addins

I have a an app registered in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com. It is hosted and I entered the hostname in the Platforms section. How can I add a localhost url for when I want to debug my app? It seems that I cannot add another Web API platoform? What is the best practice? Do I need to register another app and put the localhost url there and just change my manifest file?

Comment: Also registering applications in apps.dev.microsoft.com will cease to exist soon (May'19) and there is a new preview feature for App Registration in portal.azure.com under Azure Active Directory blade

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another redirect url for debugging. If you just want to debug your code, there is no need to register another app.
[image]

You can edit the Application Manifest to add reply urls.
[image]

Or you can do it in Azure portal.
[image]
[image]

However, if you want to change the permissions to debug, to avoid affecting your production environment, you'd better register another app.

Comment: @nmrlqa4 Then you can edit the manifest to add the reply urls, you can also add the reply urls in Azure portal.

Comment: @nmrlqa4 I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: @nmrlqa4 Do you have any other concerns regarding this?